# Angular conditional formatting json

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a little app written in jquery and wanna translate it to angularjs.

But I need some suggestions on if it's possible to make with angularJs. In my app I make some ajax call, retrieve a Json and then parse it and inject into the dom.

The problem here is that my json property are: simple string, array or nested json objects.

So when I parse the json I format it: for example I loop over array and build a table of data, or parse a string and get the length of the string. Then I output all to the dom.

This is a bit verbose in jquery, but make it possible. I would like to know if I can make something similar with AngularJs.

```
$.each(data.ALLIMG, function(i, image) {
    if(image.alt){
        $("#imagesDetail").append("<li>ALT:" + image.alt + " SRC: ");
        $("#imagesDetail").append(image.src + "</li>");
        totalAltImg++;
    }
});
$("#text").append("<p>" + data.TEXT + "</p>");
$("#text").append("<p><b>Length: </b>" + data.TEXT.LENGTH + " character(s)</p>");
```

In my knowledge of angular I should use something like `{{text}}` but if it's an array how I output a table? or a list?

Comment: For an array you'd use ng-repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a full working example.  You can use `ng-show` to test if the property is there although in this example it would render hidden however it is much simpler than a filter.  I've also provided a simple filter full example.  The data.TEXT I just assumed you wanted to count the characters of that text.

Demo:  http://plnkr.co/br2M4GXrDENd4rLkDBho

```
<!-- with ngshow -->
<ul id="imagesDetail">
  <li ng-repeat="image in data.ALLIMG" ng-show="image.alt">
     ALT: {{image.alt}} SRC: {{image.src}}
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- with filter see below -->
<ul id="imagesDetail2">
  <li ng-repeat="image in data.ALLIMG | filter:hasAlt" >
    ALT: {{image.alt}} SRC: {{image.src}}
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="text">
  <p>{{data.TEXT}}</p>
  <p><b>Length: </b> + {{data.TEXT.length}} character(s)</p>
</div>
```

controller filter:

```
 $scope.hasAlt = function(image) {
  return image.alt!==undefined;
 }
```

Comment: One thing you should note that the controller generally should not be doing any Dom manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Should look something like

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat='image in data.ALLIMG'> ALT: {{image.alt}} {{image.src}}</li>
</ul>
```

If you need to filter out invalid data (like you do in your example), you can define a filter predicate in your controller:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat='image in data.ALLIMG| filter:properImages'> 
     ALT: {{image.alt}} {{image.src}}</li>
</ul>
```